# Single Instance OpenStack IP Network Configuration

Tags: linux, networking, ip, openstack

Am curious about how OpenStack handles IP configuration, i have a complete working openstack dashboard with a static IP of 192.168.1.73/24 and i want to change it to something else. Running as a VM using Scientific Linux as the Guest Host.

Am running openstack-queens (repo) -- /etc/yum.repos.d

What i've tried and failed...

1.Changing static IP in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

2.Made sure in /etc/resolv.conf reflects my new configuration.

2.Replacing IP configuration in packstack-answerfile for the compute node and the rest of the services i've configured.

What i have noted!!!

1.systemctl status -l redis.service --- fails when i change the IP configuration, this is active (running) with its initial configuration.

2.Virtualization daemon also fails during boot

How "deep" does Networking go for OpenStack and how do i achieve my goals of setting a different IP and still have my dashboard up and running?

Answer (score 0):

This was Easy:
What I missed to do is to only re-run my packstack answerfile.

First, change the IP address on the machine in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br-ex thats if you already gone ahead in setting up networking for your OpenStack Env.

If you have done a backup of your ifcfg-eth0, revert to it and change to new IP configuration.

Second, Replace new IP configuration in packstack-answerfile for the compute node and the rest of the services configured.

Last But not Least:
Requires Steady Internet Connection!!!

Last Step is to re-run your packstack-answerfile with the new IP configuration.